# How can I make creator properties and recipients not "swap" correctly?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Hi there I am trying to replicate the functionality of stock SMS messages. The issue I'm having is that when I reply to a card that I "created" and sent to another person it puts my image as the recipient.

Heres the timeline items json:

```
"text":message,

    "notification": {
        "level": "DEFAULT"
    },
    "creator": {
        "displayName": "Me",
        "imageUrls": [
            fromimage
        ]
    },
    "recipients": [{
        "displayName": "Them",
        "imageUrls": [
            toimage
        ]
    }],
    "menuItems": [
        {
            "action": "REPLY"
        }
    ]
};
```

When I reply I want it to be this:

```
...
        "creator": {
             "displayName": "Them",
            "imageUrls": [
                toimage
            ]

        },
        "recipients": [{
           "displayName": "Me",
            "imageUrls": [
                fromimage
            ]   
        }],
    ...
```

Instead I get this:

```
 ...
            "creator": {
                 "displayName": "Me",
                "imageUrls": [
                    fromimage
                ]

            },
            "recipients": [{
               "displayName": "Me",
                "imageUrls": [
                    fromimage
                ]   
            }],
        ...
```

So right now I'm patching the timeline card when I get notification of reply but it still shows my picture as the background when I reply "to myself"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as intended: when the user replies to a timeline card, the user is indeed the creator of the reply timeline card and the recipients are the creator or the recipients (minus the user) of the original timeline card.